# Why can I clone the main repository but not a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

I have a branch of a repository on github I am trying to clone.  i can clone the main repository at the url https://github.com/pmyusername/myrepository (not actual link since the data is private).  However, I cannot clone the branch located at https://github.com/myusername/myrepository/tree/branchname .  To clone the repository, I simply needed to run:

```
git clone https://github.com/myusername/myrepository
```

but if i try to run:

```
https://github.com/myusername/myrepository/tree/branchname
```

I receive the error:

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myusername/myrepository/tree/branchname' not found
```

but I know it exists because i am copying and pasting it from the url.  The problem might have to do with the fact that I pay to keep it private, but i don't think so.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to clone the branch if you already have the entire repository?

Comment: The branch is further along than the repository.  The repository is outdated.

Comment: The repository by definition, contains all branches.  The `master` branch may be outdated, but you can still checkout the branch in question (after a git fetch/pull that is).

Comment: Why not just clone and then checkout the branch? Git will always need a master branch, if you want to use that branch as master, you are looking at forking from that branch.

Comment: I am new to github.  How is that done?

Comment: git clone <url to repo> && git fetch && git checkout -b branchname

Comment: When I clone the repository, none of the files that are only in the branch I need are copied to my computer.  I need the files from the branch on my computer.

Comment: you need to clone the repository, and then switch your local working repository to the desired branch. You do that with the git checkout command. Take a look at this http://git-scm.com/book it's an entire book on git that has been open sourced for your benefit.

Comment: If he really, really just wanted to clone the branch, shouldn't it work with git clone -b branchname git@github.com:user/project.git?

Comment: sean, I tried the command you wrote.  It cloned the master branch, not the branch I typed in.  Im going to take a look at the book now.

Comment: Philip, Sean meant that you should clone the entire repo and then checkout the branch you need.

Comment: I am confused.  Do i do git fetch branchname and then git checkout branchname?

Comment: After you 'git clone' to pull down the repository, you run 'git fetch' so that your local copy of the repository is aware of all the remote branches. You can then run a 'git checkout -b branchname' (you might put origin/branchname) to set your local working branch to track the remote branch.

Comment: When I do git fetch it asks me to specify the remote repository.  If I specify  'https://github.com/myusername/myrepository', and then checkout the branch, I am still left with the master branch (not the one i want) on my local computer.  If I specify 'https://github.com/myusername/myrepository/tree/branchname', it says "fatal: repository is not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to aggregate all the comments into a succinct response...
Step 1:  `git clone https://github.com/myusername/myrepository`
Step 2:  `git fetch`
Step 3:  `git checkout -b desired_branch`  # add origin/desired_branch to end of command line to set up remote tracking

UPDATE:
Just did a quick experiment with daniellarsson's suggestion, and it appears to work:
`i:work> git clone -b metro git@github.com:user/project.git

i:work> cd project

I:\work\project> git branch -a

* metro

  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master

  remotes/origin/master

  remotes/origin/metro`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UI like GitEx, you can mention the branch you want to clone in the dialog box the appears. This would clone the repo with the branch checked out automatically.

[image]